# Ubuntu One Music Playlist doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

Am I the only one that is not able to make playlists with ubuntu one on android?  Everytime i make one, it says network error.  I have tried it on wifi and 3g with no luck as well as restarting my phone.  Any solutions?

Comment: I have the same problem on my HTC Inspire. I just get an error message: "Failed to save play list, please try later. A network error occurred. Try again later."

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).